Kubernetes IndexedJob not creating sufficient amount of pods
I deployed an IndexedJob with completions=100000 and parallelism=500.
After about 1500 pods that have mostly finished with COMPLETED state, the job doesn't create anymore pods.
There isn't any clear error, event or log that i have found to diagnose the reason.
The job state is (describe):
Name:               my-job
Namespace:          aux
Selector:           batch.kubernetes.io/controller-uid=65b67cb3-ccb3-41ea-8e0a-f1374d9efbf3
Labels:             batch.kubernetes.io/controller-uid=65b67cb3-ccb3-41ea-8e0a-f1374d9efbf3
                    batch.kubernetes.io/job-name=my-job
                    controller-uid=65b67cb3-ccb3-41ea-8e0a-f1374d9efbf3
                    job-name=my-job
Annotations:        batch.kubernetes.io/job-tracking: 
Parallelism:        500
Completions:        100000
Completion Mode:    Indexed
Start Time:         Thu, 18 Apr 2024 16:19:46 +0300
Pods Statuses:      0 Active (0 Ready) / 1474 Succeeded / 482 Failed
Completed Indexes:  0-6,10-34,36-39,41-90,92-117,122-127,129-155,160,162,...
Pod Template:
  Labels:           batch.kubernetes.io/controller-uid=65b67cb3-ccb3-41ea-8e0a-f1374d9efbf3
                    batch.kubernetes.io/job-name=my-job
                    controller-uid=65b67cb3-ccb3-41ea-8e0a-f1374d9efbf3
                    job-name=my-job
  Service Account:  primary
  Containers:
   my-job:
    Image:      my-job
    Port:       <none>
    Host Port:  <none>
    Requests:
      cpu:     1
      memory:  4Gi
    Environment:
      ****:  ****
    Mounts:        <none>
  Volumes:         <none>
Events:
  Type    Reason            Age                   From            Message
  ----    ------            ----                  ----            -------
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  51m (x1403 over 62m)  job-controller  (combined from similar events): Created pod: my-job-1409-r5p4r

The job's manifest:
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: 'my-job'
spec:
  completions: 100000
  parallelism: 500
  completionMode: Indexed
  template:
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Never
      nodeSelector:
        cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool: some-nodepool
      tolerations:
      - key: "some-toleration-key"
        value: "some-toleration-value"
        effect: "NoSchedule"
      containers:
      - name: my-job
        image: 'my-job'
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "4Gi"
            cpu: "1"

The cluster is running on GKE
kubectl version

Client Version: v1.29.3
Kustomize Version: v5.0.4-0.20230601165947-6ce0bf390ce3
Server Version: v1.27.7-gke.1121002

Additionally, the job is configured to run on a specific nodepool which initially has 0 nodes. Once deployed, enough nodes are starting (by the cluster autoscaler). After the Job finish creating the pods, the nodepool is scaled back down to 0.
I have tried to run the job on multiple, different completions/parallelism setups but the behavior remains the same.
